# Print Array Key Multidimensional within a Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array (Getting data from an excel file) which I have been trying to "merge" the data dependent on the ID. I have managed to create the array (Grouping the products to the ID), which results in the following.

```
Array ( [Order10] => Array ( [Mr Name] => Array ( [45 STREET] => Array ( [AREA] => Array ( [Product1] => 1 [Product2] => 3 ) ) ) ) )
```

I am now trying to to get the data extracted (Order, Name, Street etc.), but am only managing to extract the ID (Order10) using key(var). Here is a basic layout of what the code is currently like.

```
//Gets Data from excel file
foreach ($bulk as $prod)
{
    $APIOrder[] = array('Order' => $prod['ORDER'],
                         'Prod' => $prod['PROD'],
                        'Quantity' => $prod['QTY'],
                        'Recipient_Name' => $prod['RECIPIENT_NAME']);
}

$newOptions = array();
foreach ($APIOrder as $option)
{
    $Order = $option['Order'];
    $Prod = $option['Prod'];
    $Qty = $option['Quantity']; //Added
    $Recipient_Name = $option['Recipient_Name'];
    $newOptions[$Order][$Recipient_Name][$Prod] = $Qty;
}

$index4 = 0;

foreach($newOptions as $key=>$val)
{
    $SeperateOptions = (array_slice($newOptions, $index4, true));
    //Print Array to check, Echo ID, Name, Product
    $index4++;
}
```

I can get this data extracted if I do not have the code within a foreach loop. The problem with this is the order is repeated depending on how many products are on an order, which makes inserting the order into a database system abit harder. Below example:

```
Array ( [Order10] => Array ( [Mr Name] => Array ( [45 STREET] => Array ( [AREA] => Array ( [Product1] => 1) ) ) ) )
Array ( [Order10] => Array ( [Mr Name] => Array ( [45 STREET] => Array ( [AREA] => Array ( [Product2] => 3) ) ) ) )
```

As I have said, I can extract the data if I don't try to put all products within the array, but then I would have to create a loop when the data is being sent to the database to add the missing products. Any sort of direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can not do this. In PHP the array keys should be unique, and can be only a string or an integer. Your existing array is good.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Thanks for the reply, so keep it with the one array (With mulitple products). How would I go "extracting" the key names such as address? This is a problem I am having with my current way.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but based on comments between OP and me, I try to show him, how I do that and it's too long, and here are code formatting. The key is the id of order, everyhing in an array then what has more than 1 value. `products` is an array too. Try always keep related things enclosed.:

```
$orders = [
    'Order10' => [
        'name' => 'Mr Name',
        'address' => [
            'street' => 'street here',
            'country' => 'country here',
            'zipcode' => 'zipcode here'
        ],
        'phones' => [
            'mobile' => 'mobile phone here',
            'fax' => 'fax here',
            'workplace' => 'here'
        ],
        'products' => [
            'productId1',
            'productId2',
            //and so on
        ]
    ]
];
```

and then you can iterate your order array like this to show:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
        ?>
        <div>Name: <?php echo $order['name']; ?></div>
        <div>Address: <?php echo $order['address']['zipcode']; ?>, <?php echo $order['address']['country']; ?>, <?php echo $order['address']['street']; ?>    </div>
        <div>Products: 
            <?php
            foreach ($order['products'] as $procutId) {
                $Produt = new Procut($productId);
                ?>
                <div><?php echo $Product->getName(); ?></div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

In my example, I have a `Product` class, maybe you are not using classes, but of course, you can create a `getProcut($id)` function to get a product by `id`, so it could be

```
$product = getProduct($procutId);
echo $product['name'];
```

This is your decision.

Comment: Thanks again @lolka_bolka. The product class isn't really needed for this as it is reading orders from an excel file (I am using classes on others). I will look into your example and try to adapt it. Thanks again for the help!